# Austin Allegro 1981 - Clutch is not working properly

Tags: clutch

I recently had a manual transmission repaired because it was slipping out of 4th gear while driving down the road. I took out the engine/transmission and gave the transmission to a local garage to overhaul. After getting the transmission back, I put everything back together and now the car is acting strangely. I put the car in 1st gear and start going and get a lot of clanking noises and can not shift to 2nd.

Prior to doing this job, the car was shifting nicely. Now with the engine stopped and in neutral the car will roll easily. If I depress the clutch it will also roll easily. However if I put it into 1st gear with the clutch still depressed, it will stop rolling. I'm not sure if it is the clutch or transmission. I took out the clutch again but could not find the problem. But after putting the clutch back and taking it for a test, it was working properly. But then after 2 kilometres, I got the clanking back and grinding the gears trying to put it in 2nd.

I would be grateful for any help. The car is an Austin Allegro 1981.

Thanks

tony

Comment: Are you sure you put the clutch pressure plate back in the correct way (facing correctly)?

Comment: Hi Paulster2. thanks for the reply. I believe it is correct. It is front wheel drive and can only go one way on. I've done this before when I overhauled the engine and everything went back together ok for 14 years. So I'm at a loss what went wrong now. I took out the clutch assemby earlier today and will take it to the garage that sold it to my wife when it was new. hope the gentleman who fixed the transmission will take a look at it. Problem is that he's on pension and goes to the garage as a hoby. will let you know.

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like it's being caused by the clutch not releasing properly. I think the Allegro uses a Hydraulic clutch, so it's likely to be one of three things:

- Insufficient movement of the clutch pressure plate - if the sprinngs or fingers are worn, it might not be working properly.
- Insufficient movement of the clutch release arm - This could be bent or cracked - I've even heard of them breaking in two on some cars of that era.
- Insufficient movement of the slave cylinder - either it's sticking, or the hydraulics aren't working properly - it might just need bleeding...